# Drawing a lot of rectangles in GDI+

Tags: c#, performance, gdi+

I have an application drawing a lot of small rectangles (about 1 million) using GDI+ in C# and the performance is... not so good. I understand that constructing a lot of `Rectangle` objects for passing them to `Graphis.FillRectangle` takes some time. I also understand that I cannot avoid this if the `Rectangle`s change from from frame to frame, because `Rectangle` is designed to be immutable. My question therefore is: is there any possibility to improve the performance of this drawing call except if all `Rectangle`s must be assumed to be visible?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: Instantiating Rectangles will take almost no time compared to the actual API call. In fact, Rectangle is a struct.

Comment: Do you mean 1-thousand or 1-million?

Comment: There is almost surely a better way. What do the Rectangles represent? What are you trying to draw?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest you use the array variant of the call instead:

```
FillRectangles(Brush brush, Rectangle[] rects);
```

If that does not work for you because you need different brushes or the like, you should group the primitives by state (brush) and draw the arrays each in a single go. A quick test shows at least three times the performance, i.e. 300K Rectangles drawn individually feel about as choppy as 1M Rectangles drawn in one go.

Comment: FillRectangles is soo slow. got anything faster?   no wonder android pushed 2d acceleration into the operating system,  because its not the developers job to accelerate  filling rectangles.. on windows there is no acceleration, and you are left with a poorly performing app. don't worry, by 2050 I think PC hardware should be fast enough for the FillRectangles function.  I'll be waiting patiently.

Comment: using dotTrace I can see all the poor performing functions even using 2017 hardware it still performs badly.. they include:   FillRectangles,  DrawImageUnscaled (GDIPdrawImageI),  DrawImage (GdipDrawImageRect)

Comment: @hamish use WPF instead of the old GDI+

Comment: @juFo I tried to use WPF, but there is little to no working WPF examples for all the 60 features I am currently using. I calculated it will take me 19 months to convert from GDI+ to WPF.